# OpenGL ES 2.0 Shader Float Data Precision

Tags: opengl-es, shader, fragment-shader

Here is my whole fragment shader code, it's quite simple:

```
precision highp float;

void main( void )
{  
   float a = 66061311.0;
   if(a == 66061312.0)
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   else
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

Why the screen is clear to red.
When I set a to 66061315.0, the screen is clear to green.
That confuses me. Under my understanding, 66061311.0 is within the range of float type.

How can I fix or go around this?

Comment: FIrst, don't post code as images. Just insert it properly into your question. Second, we have no idea what values the components of `color` hold. Second, we don't know with which precision your float is declared. If you chose `precision mediump float;`, then your representable integer range is minimally `[-2^15, 2^15 -1]` which is of course less than your left-hand operand.

Comment: Sorry, I hava modified the question. I use the highp precision. But the result is still the same as before. I tried in the PC and Android Mobile Phone with ARM Mali GPU, the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the value is within the range of the type it does not mean that its precision is precise enough at such large values to see a difference between the two.

In your case for a standard 32-bit `float` the results are:

```
66061311.0 = 6.60613e+07
66061312.0 = 6.60613e+07
```

And the values are the same when comparing. This is not related or bound to openGL nor shaders, it is how a `float` is defined. A 64-bit `float` will detect a difference though.

To add a bit more info if you check the [definition of a floating value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) you will see that the fraction only has 23 bits which means the precition is up to 8.4M but you have over 66M.